# How to select option from invisible drop-down element in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please anyone help me how to find the invisible  element in Selenium WebDriver. I want to select an option from the drop down and my target is to find element is through ID.

But in the HTML tag the element is not visible to select the option. I verified so many question in that they are mentioning use JavascriptExceutor.

Can any one please help me the java script for the html tag:

```
<select id="periodId" name="period" style="display: none;">
<option value="l4w">Last 4 Weeks</option>
<option value="l52w">Last 52 Weeks</option>
<option value="daterange">Date Range</option>
<option value="weekrange">Week Range</option>
<option selected="" value="monthrange">Month Range</option>
<option value="yeartodate">Year To Date</option>
</select>
```

Comment: provide a fiddle please

Comment: Why would you want Selenium to select an element that a human can't?

Comment: @RossPatterson couldn't agree more.  this is bad testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally agree with Ross Patterson, but if you still want to try the above scenario,this might work...

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('select#periodId').click();");
```

Comment: This assumes the page has jQuery on it. Not unlikely but still many pages don't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('periodId').style.display='inline';");
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("periodId")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Last 4 Weeks");
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('periodId').style.display='none';");
```